# NoClassDefFoundError: io/opencensus/trace/Tracestate thrown when StorageClient is instantiated

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage

I have a spring boot 2.1 app and I'm just following the documentation from the Firebase site but I'm getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/opencensus/trace/Tracestate.

```
public void initialize() {
    InputStream serviceAccount = getClass()
        .getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_PATH);

    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
           .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
            .setStorageBucket(BUCKET_NAME)
            .build();

    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

    StorageClient storageClient = StorageClient.getInstance(); // This line is throwing the exception
}
```

I was not able to find any info about this and I cannot figure out what is wrong here.

EDIT:
I have both dependencies in my pom.xml, firebase admin and google cloud storage, removing firebase admin the error stop happening.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
    <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
    <version>6.8.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
    <version>1.74.0</version>
</dependency>
```